# Why does the outline of this text input display differently in Chrome than Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, css

I've written this fiddle to demo the problem. I have a simple form. When a textbox gets focus all I wish to happen is for the textbox's background to change. In Firefox 9 this works fine. In Chrome it seems to incorrectly alter the input's outline. Even If I explicitly set it. Chrome changes it and puts a black outline around the input on focus.

Here's the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H3qay/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, WebKit (used by Safari and Chrome) applies a negative [`outline-offset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#outline-offset) to focused form inputs. You can see it in the following CSS rule for focused form inputs in [WebKit's default style sheet](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css):

```
input:focus, textarea:focus, isindex:focus, keygen:focus, select:focus {
    outline-offset: -2px
}
```

So undoing this is simply a matter of setting it to `0`:

```
input:focus
{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    outline-offset: 0;
}
```

[Updated jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H3qay/3)